# How to get list of installed applications on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

In Windows 7 and older, installed applications were listed under this registry key in HKEY_USER:
`Software(/Wow6432Node)/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Uninstall`

I've tried to find installation date and the exe path in the Windows 10 registry, but I'm not sure which key to use (including apps from windows store).

I found following keys, but are they reliable? Is there an easier way to collect such data?

- Installation time: 
  `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\Repository\Families\`
- Display name, directory: 
  `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\Repository\Packages`
- Company, name, description: 
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\AppX*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask to the WMI of your computer.

1. Type wmic in Run (Win+R)
2. Type product get name (Enter)

You can redirect the output to a specific file with this command :

```
/output:C:\InstallList.txt product get name
```

Comment: Wmic doesn't list Windows Store apps. Only installed with Windows Installer.

Comment: With powershell you can list the "metro" apps : `Get-AppxPackage`

Comment: In case anyone wants the full command to copy and paste:
`wmic /output:C:\InstallList.txt product get name`

Comment: Get-AppxPackage is just a Powershell cmdlet wrapper for Windows.Deployment.Management.PackageManager.FindPackages*() - the true 'enumerate packages on the machine and/or reigstered for users'. See MSDN for more details => https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br240960?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Just to be clear here: if you have already opened the wmic console then simply run "product get name". Also, chances are that you cannot write to C:\ unless elevated so run "/output:c:\users\yourname\installed.txt product get name" if you want the list written to file. Finally, the list produced is not all that accurate. I have numerous (non-Windows app store) applications installed that are not listed, e.g. Visual Studio Code. So you might also want to look at something like Belarc Advisor.

Answer (score 3):

Powershell

`Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table –AutoSize`

Comment: Adding the "Sort-Object -Property DisplayName | Format-Table –AutoSize" could be useful if you want alphabetical. Would be nice if we can get similar information using "wmic" command.

Comment: Various places seem to need to be checked. The above is just one place and thus incomplete. (I do not have a list of all the places to check - that is what makes this task to difficult, and results in so many suggested solutions which are incomplete.)

Answer (score -3):

Click Windows button
Click on Setting icon 
Click on APP and Features
 Here is your list of applications installed on your windows 10