# Uninstall all software starting with a specific string

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, command-line, uninstallation

Following [this issue](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/NI-DAQmx-Driver-support-for-LabVIEW-2017-is-missing/m-p/3644737/highlight/true#M1023406), I want to uninstall all the National Instrument software. From [here](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/six-ways-removeuninstall-windows-programs-and-apps) first enter the `wmic` in CMD. Then using the command `product get name` I get a bunch of software all starting with `NI`:

```
NI Logos 19.0
NI Trace Engine
NI-MXDF 19.0.0f0 for 64 Bit Windows
WIF Core Dependencies Windows 19.0.0
NI-VISA USB Passport 19.0.0
NI-VISA SysAPI x64 support 19.0.0
NI Controller Driver 19.0 64-bit
NI ActiveX Container (64-bit)
Math Kernel Libraries
NI MXS 19.0.0
NI LabWindows/CVI 2019 Network Variable Library
NI-VISA GPIB Passport 19.0.0
NI LabWindows/CVI 2017 Low-Level Driver (Original)
NI-RPC 17.0.0f0 for Phar Lap ETS
NI LabWindows/CVI 2017 .NET Library (64-bit)
...
```

I can uninstall them individually by for example:

```
product where name="NI Logos 19.0" call uninstall
```

and then I have to select `y`/`Y`. Given there are a lot of these software which I have to uninstall, I was wondering how I can automatize this process. The steps should be something like this:

1. find all the lines in `product get name` starting with `NI` and make a list out of it
2. a for loop on the above list running `product where name=list[i] call uninstall` with the default `y`/`Y`

I would appreciate if you could help me with this issue. Thanks for your support in advance.

**P.S.** Powershell solutions are also ok. In fact, any other solution to uninstall all of these using any other way is OK for me.

Comment: You forgot to mention that this is a `wmic` command, I guess you didn't follow completely the hints at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32209561/how-to-get-list-of-installed-applications-on-windows-10)

Comment: @LotPings isn't `wmic` a CMD command? What is the difference? I hadn't seen the above post. I used [this post](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/six-ways-removeuninstall-windows-programs-and-apps).

Comment: @Foad `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe` is an executable which outputs text not with one byte per character as most executables, but in Unicode using UTF-16 Little Endian encoding. This difference in character encoding must be taken into account on processing text output of `wmic`.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the `Like` operator with [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic).

From [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)

```bat
WMIC Product Where "Name Like 'NI%'" Call Uninstall /NoInteractive
```

From a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)

```bat
WMIC Product Where "Name Like 'NI%%'" Call Uninstall /NoInteractive
```

No command line options are documented as available to to the `Uninstall` call, so using `/NoInteractive` is offered here more in hope than as a definitive solution to your stated prompt.

Comment: tried this, It seems the software is being uninstalled, but then after a restart, everything is still there!

Comment: If that's the case, then that is not the fault of my answer, I used the same `WMIC` method that you have stated works. Did you run the script as Administrator, to ensure that the required uninstall permissions were in place?

Comment: It is indeed not the fault of your answer, but the fact that I presumed the command I introduced in the original post is working. Which apparently is not the case!

Comment: I have not seen previous indications of `Call Uninstall` not working in the manner you have described, _certainly not without some sort of error indicated upon invoking_, it is after all a documented method of doing so. Additionally, you are aware that using `win32_product` only covers those products which were installed using Windows Installer, aren't you?

Answer (score 1):

If the applications were installed from an MSI you could use the following PowerShell code. If some other installer was used, you could add the silent uninstall parameters to the `$uninstallString` in the loop:

```
$productNames  = @("^NI")
$uninstallKeys = @('HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall',
                   'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall')

foreach ($key in (Get-ChildItem $uninstallKeys)) 
{
    foreach ($productName in $productNames)
    {
        $name = $key.GetValue("DisplayName")
        if ($name -match $productName) 
        {
            $uninstallString = $key.GetValue("UninstallString")
            if ($uninstallString -match "^msiexec(\.| )")
            {
                $uninstallString = ($uninstallString -replace "/I{","/X{" -replace "/X{", '/X "{' -replace "}",'}"')  + " /qn /norestart"
            }

            Write-Host "Removing '$name' using '$uninstallString'..."
            & cmd.exe /C $uninstallString
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this properly. what do you mean by "silent uninstall parameters"? I would appreciate if you could elaborate.

Comment: Well, I don't know which parameters these uninstallation programs need, so it might be required to add a `/s` or `/quiet` or whatever, to make them unattended. But just add a `#` before the `& cmd ...` statement and run the code. If all the used uninstall strings start with msiexec, you won't have to change anything